# Meaning of "*:" in java classpath specification

Tags: java, command-line

I have a Java project uncompiled. Entry point is the main method in `maui.main.MauiModelBuilder` which is passed some parameters by command line.

The author of the code provides this suggestion to compile it:

```
java -cp "lib/*:src" maui.main.MauiModelBuilder -l data/automatic_tagging/train/ -m test -v none
```

What's the meaning of `"lib/*:src"` in this case? I never saw such a syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, you are parsing this syntax incorrectly in your head. You should be reading it as `"lib/*"` and `"src"`. This syntax means that we are adding:

- all files under the `lib` folder
- the src file

to the classpath of `java`.

`:` is used as a separator for classpath entry.

Answer (score 1):

'*' is a wildcard character that match anything.

In this case 'lib/*'  add all file under 'lib' directory and ':' is a seperator thus 'src' also included.

So your 'lib/*:src' add all file under 'lib' directory and 'src'  under current directory.

Comment: What about the `:src` part?

Answer (score 0):

`"lib/*:src"` means to include all files under lib directory and src. ":" is used as separator,